# Server.MapPath and window.open()

Tags: c#, javascript, window.open, server.mappath

I'm actually working on an app that provides the possibility to the users to upload the files they wish. Those files should also be visualizable once uploaded.

In order to do that I'm trying to get the file path with Server.MapPath and a concatenation of other values. The file path is passed as an argument in a window.open javascript function.

My problem is that I do not get any result at all. No window is opened.

Here is my code:

```
string completeUrl = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsersImagesUploadFolder"] + CurrentUserLogin +
                               @"\\" + ((GridDataItem) e.Item)["Url"].Text);

string radWindowOpen = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('" + completeUrl + "')</" + "script>";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "fileDisplay", radWindowOpen);
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but I don't see what it is.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `Server.MapPath` gives you a physical path on a server. Assigning the result of this method to a variable called `completeUrl` seems misleading at best, and is probably the start of your confusion.

Comment: So you are suggesting to put the Server.MapPath method and all directly as argument ?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that if you're looking to return something to the client, `Server.MapPath` probably isn't part of the solution at all.

Answer (score 2):

As Damien has pointed out, `Server.MapPath` is used for server side path mapping. Clients need to see a path underneath your web app.

For example:

`Page.ResolveUrl("~/uploads/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsersImagesUploadFolder"] ...`

Would resolve a to `http://mydomain/vroot/uploads/...` etc.

As an aside, note also that `@"\\"` would result in a double backslash, which I don't think you intended.

Either of `@"\"` or `"\\"` would result in a single backslash.

Comment: Ok, now I get it and it works as intended. I was actually completely missing the point. Thank you.